How to fetch and store real-time Solana token data for charting?
Description
I’m working on a project where I need to fetch detailed Solana token information in real-time, given a token mint address. My goal is to store time-series token information such as price and transactions, and then present this data in a chart or list.
What I’ve Tried
I’ve explored several online services and APIs, including Solana JSON RPC, bloxRoute, Helius, and Pump.fun. While I found some useful features, I haven’t been able to piece together a solid solution that meets my needs.
Specific Problem

Identifying the best API or service to fetch real-time token data.
Efficiently storing this data in a time-series database like
TimescaleDB.
Presenting the data in a chart or list format.

Request for Help
Could anyone with experience in Solana token data fetching and time-series data storage provide guidance or examples on how to achieve this? Any recommendations on APIs, database schemas, or charting libraries would be greatly appreciated.

One of the ways might be to run private RPC with Geyser plugin.
Here is some documentation to get you started: https://docs.solanalabs.com/validator/geyser
